# Is this sentence anastrophe?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure, inversion

I came across the sentence

> Pretty soon along came some people.

However I wonder if

> Some people came along pretty soon.

is correct. Is this sentence anastrophe?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original context? It's a rather unusual combination of "informal" ***pretty soon*** coupled with a "dated, poetic" non-standard reordering of the normal form *some people came [along]*, which leads me to suspect it wasn't written by a native speaker.

Comment: This sentence is from the book "The little house" but the content can be seen because of copyright.

Comment: Is that [the 1942 children's book?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_House_(novel)) It's not the kind of phrasing one would expect people to say today (or even *write*, unless they were facetiously imitating an outdated/childish style), But as regards ***along***, it's an optional word there (which could be replaced with ***by*** in the "standard" word order). It just adds the implication that those people probably arrived / "turned up" at that place *by chance*, rather than because that's where they were trying to get to.

Comment: Yes, but your link is wrong.  it's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_House

Comment: Like [Little Miss Muffet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Miss_Muffet): "*Along came* a spider", although rhyming also is a factor here. Could you add a few lines before and after yours? That should fall within fair use, though you should add a citation regarding the source in your question.

Comment: @Yuuichi: An *anastrophe* is an [extremely] ***unusual*** rearrangement of "normal" word order. Technically speaking I suppose you could say that about your text, but it's not *that* unusual, and wouldn't be considered a "typical" example of anastrophe, if at all. On the other hand, *Pretty soon **came along** some people* would definitely qualify as anastophic.

Answer (score -1):

The first is casual and informal but not especially unusual in British English. The second one sounds clumsy and strange to me.

"I put some rubbish out ready for the bin men last night and, of course, pretty soon along come the local foxes and now it's all over the street" is a similar example I heard recently.

Comment: I think your got these two the wrong way around. OP's #1 is a dated / poetic / "nursery story" usage. The relatively unusual juxtaposition of colloquial ***pretty soon*** and "literary, marked" subject/verb inversion might not be out of place in a [Brer Rabbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%27er_Rabbit) tale, but it's definitely not the idiomatic standard for today's spoken contexts. OP's #2 is absolutely "ordinary".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Where would such an ugly construction be ordinary English? "Pretty soon after" or "pretty soon afterwards" would be more normal but ending after "soon" seems, at best, American.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's actually not subject-verb inversion, but subject-dependent inversion.  But I have to agree with you.  Since this type of subject-dependent inversion appears mainly in storytelling contexts, it does sound rather odd next to the colloquial *pretty soon*, doesn't it?

Comment: @snail - I agree with you and Fumble about the storytelling thing. _Pretty soon along came some people_ has a similar "ring" to it as _Once upon a time_ (words that, if they weren't so familiar, might sound a little awkward.)

Comment: @snailboat: That's why I haven't posted an answer, and why you *should* (you're more up on the precise application of grammatical terminology). I'm inclined to believe *anastrophe* is too "strong" a term for this particular inversion, since we're so familiar with it from the "stylized story-telling" context that it's even possible for Nagora here to classify it as *more normal than the "normal" version*. Your (definitive?) ruling on whether it could properly be called an "anastrophe" would be useful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm still wondering what country you are thinking of when you say that #2 is normal. Living in England I would say that I've never heard or read that version and it would sound strange. #1 is not "normal", it definitely has a quaint ring to it, but I hear it in relaxed speech from time to time.

Comment: @Nagora: I mentioned *Brer Rabbit* specifically because OP's exact text is somewhat reminiscent of that context (as *American* children's stories; I know Enid Blyton did *her* versions, but I'm pretty sure she'd never have used the American collocation ***pretty soon***). But focusing specifically on the "anastrophic" aspect that OP's asking about, we can discard that and switch to just a proper noun instead of *some people*. Compare *John came along* with *Along came John*, and I'm sure you'll see which one is the "marked" version (appropriate to storytelling, not general conversation).

Comment: OK. I see. I've clarified my answer slightly. It would be nice if there were tags for American/Australian/Irish/Wherever English as opposed to English English. I usually assume the latter for obvious reasons.